# How can I centre each text element within each <div> both vertically and horizontally, so that the text is exactly in the middle

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to create nine circles, with a picture of a person in each, with the name of the indidvidual directly in the middle of each picture. Below is my HTML and CSS file. I have tried using text-align: centre however it does not look accurate? Also, it only move the text horizontally and not vertically, i.e not to the center of the image, only to the center of the TOP of the image. Thank you.

```
    <div class="friend">Stacey</div>
    <div class="Sexy">Caroline</div>
    <div class="friend"; id="best_friend">Adam</div></br>
    <div class="boss">Paul</div>
    <div class="friend">Phil</div>
    <div class"colleague"; id="archnemesis">Luca</div>
    <div class="friend">Ruth</div>
    <div class="family">Mum</div>
    <div class="enemy">Satan</div>


</body>

**My CSS file below:**

div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    }

.friend {
    border: 2px dashed #008000;
    }

.family {
    border: 2px dashed #0000FF;
}

 .enemy {
     border: 2px dashed #FF0000;
}

.colleague {
    border: 2px solid brown;
}

.boss {
    border: 5px solid pink;
}

.sexy {
    border-color: purple;
}

#best_friend {
    border: 4px solid #00C957;
}

#archnemesis {
    border: 4px solid #CC0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
span.center-content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;  
  line-height:100px; 
}
.friend {
    border: 2px dashed #008000;
    }

.family {
    border: 2px dashed #0000FF;
}

 .enemy {
     border: 2px dashed #FF0000;
}

.colleague {
    border: 2px solid brown;
}

.boss {
    border: 5px solid pink;
}

.sexy {
    border-color: purple;
}

#best_friend {
    border: 4px solid #00C957;
}

#archnemesis {
    border: 4px solid #CC0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="friend"><span class="center-content ">Stacey</span></div>
    <div class="Sexy"><span class="center-content ">Caroline</span></div>
    <div class="friend"; id="best_friend"><span class="center-content ">Adam</span></div></br>
    <div class="boss"><span class="center-content ">Paul</span></div>
    <div class="friend"><span class="center-content ">Phil</span></div>
    <div class="colleague"; id="archnemesis"><span class="center-content ">Luca</span></div>
    <div class="friend"><span class="center-content ">Ruth</span></div>
    <div class="family"><span class="center-content ">Mum</span></div>
    <div class="enemy"><span class="center-content ">Satan</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Changes**

1. Added a new span and common class to all spans - `center-content`
2. added new class in style - span.center-content
3. You will need to keep same height for div and span to get it in the middle of each div.

Either you can test the code above on your browser or else visit this demo url - https://jsfiddle.net/BRxKX/4962/

Comment: This worked, thank you. However, now when I add my image:  <div class="Sexy"; id="center-content"><img src="http://futbolfan.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Gema-3.jpg">Caroline</div> It moves the text below the image within the circle. How do I get the text to sit ON TOP of the image?

Comment: Please post your code @ jsfiddle.net for demo purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something along the lines of:

```
<div style="display:table;">
  <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
    <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This may be of help in the future http://howtocenterincss.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use `vertical-align:middle`but that requires to be a table and you can spoof it using `display:table-cell`.

I suggest to use `line-height` with the height of the circles, this works with only 1 line of text, if you one multiline you have to use internal divs or spans.

If if doesn't look accurate horizontally may be the padding.

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0;
  line-height:100px;
}
```